# Jquery Basic Portlet

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am listing students at my web page. I want to list their information something like:

http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html

However the portlets will be same size, no need for edit close buttons. I just want to show their names at every title of portlets. Also no need to be draggable or sortable. I just want to have good ui effect at my divs and wants that title for every portlet(I don't know well designing a CSS, so a library will be better for me instead of trying to get good colors)Also putting a minimize button may be good.

Is there any plugin like that at Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a jQuery UI theme CSS file along with properly formatted html.

http://jsfiddle.net/P9K3F/

Comment: Can minimize button be add to it?

Comment: Yes but you would need to utilize the jQuery js library to do so!  A simple toggle() function on the content would easily minimize the display.  No need to create a whole jQuery UI dialog instance for simple functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Best option for you is to try out some CSS. You can use `float: left|right` to organize them in that grid way, round the corners with either images or simpler (but not cross-compatible), [border-radius](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CF4QFjAA&url=http://border-radius.com/&ei=NxbaT7XTHsKj0QXS3_yRBA&usg=AFQjCNEDZ5OcRDd3S_sHAnWEl0R2hsW_jg&sig2=EMZM951A-4AMxjeAK2MbZw).